# Bitlocker GPO automatic?

Tags: windows, group-policy, bitlocker

I was wondering if someone else has accomplished on what im trying to do
i have GPO to automatic stores the keys in the AD when activated the bitlocker, but it seems that i have to do it manually, so i put a logon script bat with this

script.bat

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass \\192.168.3.150\shares\publica\sistemas\enablebitlocker.ps1
```

But the for some odd reason im getting this popup which i would want it to run it silently or is there way to automatic say yes ?

```
Safety warningRun only the trusted scripts. Scripts from the Internet can be useful, but this script coulddamage your equipment. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow it to run without this messagewarning. Do you want to run
```

this is the powershell script

```
$CdriveStatus = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint 'c:'
if ($CdriveStatus.volumeStatus -eq 'FullyDecrypted') {
    C:\Windows\System32\manage-bde.exe -on c: -recoverypassword -skiphardwaretest
}
```

Thank you

currently running server 2012 which does not allow GPO powershell

Comment: It's in the message: `If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow it to run`. My guess would be the file has the Mark of the Web.

Comment: well, I would maybe cheat it with unlock-file and a short script like from https://hostingultraso.com/help/windows/find-your-script%E2%80%99s-name-powershell and put it as first line or make 2 scripts, a other cheat would be to set the execution policy to a non blocking state

Comment: You don't _have_ to do it manually. If it's not done automatically, you're missing something. Here's how I did a few years ago, it's been working flawlessly ever since: https://noobient.com/2014/11/17/bitlocker-with-active-directory/

Comment: thanks for the reply, what i could not get it working was when the user does not have admin permissions on the computer i saw your tutorial but it does not show how it though GPO automatically without enabling manually bitlocker

Answer (score 0):

seemed to fixed it by adding the script by name instead by IP

```
\\apolo\shares\publica\sistemas\enablebitlocker.ps1
```