# Server 22, GPO & Bitlocker

Tags: group-policy, bitlocker, windows-11

I am having similar issues to this [Bitlocker GPO automatic?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1065149/bitlocker-gpo-automatic) However mine is not permissions based. It does not matter what user I log in as normal user to domain admin.

RSOP shows the policies applied, GroupPolicy operational log shows they processed properly.

Bitlocker log shows this, which looks like a smoking gun...
[image]

Drivers for this device list 1968 as publish date, but after a quick google search, apparently that is normal?

Secure boot is on, no legacy BIOS settings, UEFI only, drivers are all at latest versions, TPM shows 2.0 support and fine in the security processor details. Computer is 3 years old, runs windows 11 fine... And manually enabling bitlocker works...

Worse still is we have laptops purchased same time as the desktop, and they DO process this GPO without issue, no script to initiate it needed...

Any idea on why the GPO isn't being applied to certain computers based on the screenshot errors and ancillary information provided?